# MySQL where subselect on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, self-join

I'm trying to do a single MySQL query to select data inside a third party function, the problem I have however they only pass me the ID.  I need to use that ID to select all the related records.

Currently the MySQL statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT h.id, h.notification_id, h.status, d.detail 
FROM headers h, details d 
WHERE h.host_id = (SELECT host_id FROM headers WHERE id = '{$rowid}') 
AND h.service_id = (SELECT service_id FROM headers WHERE id = '{$rowid}') 
AND h.instance = (SELECT instance from headers where id = '{$rowid}')
AND h.id = d.header_id;
```

Now this works, but I'm thinking the poor MySQL engine is running 3 subqueries because I don't have 3 pieces of information available to me.

So I was wondering if there a way to run this with one query and one subquery to save the load on the database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with tuples (i.e. rather than looking up `host_id` and `service_id` and `instance` you'd look up the combination `(host_id, service_id, instance)`):

```
SELECT h.id, h.notification_id, h.status, d.detail 
FROM headers h
JOIN details d ON d.header_id = h.id
WHERE (h.host_id, h.service_id, h.instance) = 
  (SELECT host_id, service_id, instance FROM headers WHERE id = '{$rowid}') 
;
```

This puts criteria wehere it belongs: in the where clause (just as in your query). You select **from** headers and details **where** the combination `(host_id, service_id, instance)` matches the record with the given ID.

Comment: Which is faster a join or a tuple?

Comment: This depends on the DBMS's optimizer. A good optimizer would get to the same execution plan for both queries. I strive to have my queries as readable as possible (which often means only selecting from the tables I want to see data from and using `[NOT] IN` or `[NOT] EXISTS` rather than joining). I only change this if I really have performance issues. I don't think that above query would give you performance issues, so it would be my preference. At last it often boils down to exactly this: personal preference.

Comment: Look at it like this: Which query would be easier for you to understand, if you looked at them in three or four years :-)

Comment: By the way: as you can get several headers with several details with the queries you might want to apply an `ORDER BY` clause, to make sure that you see the records per order (and not a detail for order 1, then a detail for order 2, then a detail for order 1 again, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **SELF JOIN** to remove the multiple sub-queries.

Try this:

```
SELECT h.id, h.notification_id, h.status, d.detail 
FROM headers h 
INNER JOIN details d ON h.id = d.header_id 
INNER JOIN headers h2 ON h.host_id = h2.host_id AND h.service_id = h2.service_id AND h.instance = h2.instance 
WHERE h2.id = '{$rowid}'
```

Comment: beat me too it. `JOIN` will be much faster.